# if statement can't detect 0 in a variable

Tags: php, mysql

I'm just returning to my big website project so taken a step backwards in my php and mySQL learning. I've created a bit of a search engine for the site. I'm struggling to get it to display "No results found" when it doesn't have anything to display. For some reason I can't detect this. It's the $rows variable that holds how many records. Even though when it's displayed it displays as a "0", it doesn't seem to be treated as such at the if statement, within the for loop. When I did a var_dump it said int(0). What am I doing wrong?

```
  $result=query($qstring, $db_hostname, $db_username, $db_password, $db_database);

  $rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

  echo 'Results found '.$rows;

  for ($j = 0 ; $j < $rows ; ++$j)
  {
    $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
    if ($rows==0)
    {
       echo 'No results found';
    }
    else
    { 
       display_result($row[0],$row[1],$row[3],$row[4],$row[5]);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixes in your code:

```
$result=query($qstring, $db_hostname, $db_username, $db_password, $db_database);

$rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
if($rows>0)
{
  echo 'Results found '.$rows;    
  for ($j = 0 ; $j < $rows ; ++$j)
  {
       $r= mysql_fetch_row($result);
       display_result($r[0],$r[1],$r[3],$r[4],$r[5]);
   }
 }
else
{
    echo "No results found";
}
```

you can try this also

```
 $result=query($qstring, $db_hostname, $db_username, $db_password, $db_database);

     $rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
     if($rows>0)
     {
       echo 'Results found '.$rows;
       while ($r= mysql_fetch_row($result))
       {
           display_result($r[0],$r[1],$r[3],$r[4],$r[5]);
       }
      }
     else
     {
       echo "No results found";
     }
```

Comment: Thank you! This is my second rewrite after my initial thrown together version and I seem to remember having this issue in my first version too. It is now searching nicely and I don't have the irritating output when there's no results ;)

Comment: Ok. If you are beginner in php, then you can check www.php.net for more tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

Your for loop will not be entered because $rows is 0 so your if block will never be reached. If you change your for loop to a while loop, it will iterate through your results on it's own without the need to check $rows.

Try this approach:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result){
    // do stuff
}
```

And you should switch to mysqli. It is completely compatible. You basically just add the 'i' in your code.

Comment: Yes, but your for loop will not be entered if $rows was 0.

Comment: That is correct, but your initial version said something else. It's edited now. :) (removing my comment(s))

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at your loop. You say that `$rows` is `int(0)`. What does the loop do? It makes `$j=0`, then it continues doing the loop until the condition `$j < $rows` is false. Except... hey, the condition is always false, so it will never loop.

```
  for ($j = 0 ; $j < $rows ; ++$j)
  {
    #...
  }
```

To fix it, do the check if no results exist outside the loop.